# Install Cert through ARM with a pfx file

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

Is there a way to install a pfx cert through ARM template to vmss? I know the recommended way is to install a key vault cert to vmss through ARM. But I want to pass the cert content as base64 encoded string to the ARM template as a parameter.